# c# Sorted List get elements by Key Groups

Tags: c#, sortedlist

I have a class that implements sorted list:

```
public class Plates : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Plate>> {

    private SortedList<string, Plate> sortedPlates;

    public Plates() {
        sortedPlates = new SortedList<string, Plate>(new KeyComparer());
       
    }

   ...some additiona data such getters and setters

}
```

The KeyComparer looks like this:

```
 //Left part of comparer is bigger result is 1, right -1 , equal 0
    class KeyComparer : IComparer<string> {
        public int Compare(string x, string y) {

            //Split string into numbers
            var xs = x.Split(';');
            var ys = y.Split(';');

            //Take the smallest array
            int min = Math.Min(xs.Length, ys.Length);

            //Iterate the smallest amount of elements
            for (int i = 0; i < min; i++) {

                //Cast to integers
                int a = Convert.ToInt32(xs[i]);
                int b = Convert.ToInt32(ys[i]);

                //Compare
                //int cmp = xs[i].CompareTo(ys[i]);
                int cmp = a.CompareTo(b);

                //If values are not the same return
                if (cmp != 0)
                    return cmp;
            }

            //Elsewise give priority to the smallest one
            return xs.Length.CompareTo(ys.Length);
        }
```

The keys of the sorted lists looks like below (without brackets). The indexing is used to track groups of objects.

```
[0;0]
[0;0;0]
[0;1]
[0;1;1;0;0]
[0;2]
[0;8;1;0;0]
[0;9;1;0;0]
[0;10]
[0;10;1;0;0]
[1;0]
[1;1]
[2;1]
[2;10]
[3;1]
[3;1;2]
[3;1;4]
```

My question is how efficiently get group of objects by index. For example, I would like to retrieve  all objects with keys whose first index is 0 and the other group whose index starts by two 2.
The first thought that I could create a hash set and then group objects while inserting them into a dictionary, but I really do not think it is efficient:

```
    HashSet<int> hash = new HashSet<int>();
    Dictionary<int, List<string>> groups = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

    public void Add(Element item) {

        string key = item.GetKey();
        sortedPlates.Add(key, item);


        int firstID = item.KeyToIntArray()[0];
        if (hash.Add(firstID)) 
            groups.Add(firstID,new List<string> { key });
        else 
            groups[firstID].Add(key );

    }
```

Is there any way to have direct access to groups without looping?
Would I need to add another property to track groups?
I feel that this double loops is not efficient for very large amount of objects.

Comment: Is LINQ an option?

Comment: It is not about faster rewriting but more efficient grouping

Comment: I added a code at the last part of issue description including hash and dictionary. Is there other way than checking if such group index "firstID" is already placed ? Instead of adding elements to hashset to avoid duplicates.

Comment: If it is already sorted, couldn't you just store the index where group 0 begins and ends, and the index where group 2 begins and ends?

Comment: Dear @Daniel how could I do it? I probably missing some simple logic